# Styling dynamically added classes with :global() and data attributes

Tags: typescript, sass, svelte

I'm currently working on developing a typing game similar to monkeytype.com. Each individual letter is associated with classes that dynamically change from an empty string to either 'correct' or 'incorrect', depending on whether the user's typed input matches the expected letter.

Since Svelte automatically removes unused classes, the 'correct' and 'incorrect' classes may not exist immediately in the DOM. As a result, I'm having difficulty finding an effective way to apply distinct styles to these letter classes when they are activated.

Here is my code:

```
<script lang="ts">
    type Game = 'waiting for game' | 'in progress' | 'game over';
    type Word = string;

    let game: Game = 'waiting for game';
    let typedLetter = '';

    let words: Word[] = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'.split(' ');

    let wordIndex = 0;
    let letterIndex = 0;
    let correctLetter = 0;

    let correctLetters = 0;

    let wordsEl: HTMLDivElement;
    let letterEl: HTMLSpanElement;
    let inputEl: HTMLInputElement;

    function startGame() {
        setGameState('in progress');
    }

    function setGameState(state: Game) {
        game = state;
    }

    function updateGameState() {
        setLetter();
        checkLetter();
        nextLetter();
        resetLetter();
    }

    function setLetter() {
        const isWordCompleted = letterIndex > words[wordIndex].length - 1;

        if (!isWordCompleted) {
            letterEl = wordsEl.children[wordIndex].children[letterIndex] as HTMLSpanElement;
        }
    }

    function checkLetter() {
        const currentLetter = words[wordIndex][letterIndex];

        if (typedLetter === currentLetter) {
            letterEl.dataset.letter = 'correct';
            increaseScore();
        }

        if (typedLetter !== currentLetter) {
            letterEl.dataset.letter = 'incorrect';
        }
    }

    function increaseScore() {
        correctLetters += 1;
    }

    function nextLetter() {
        letterIndex += 1;
    }

    function resetLetter() {
        typedLetter = '';
    }

    function handleKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (event.code === 'Space') {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        if (game === 'waiting for game') {
            startGame();
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="game" data-game={game}>
    <input
        type="text"
        class="input"
        bind:this={inputEl}
        bind:value={typedLetter}
        on:input={updateGameState}
        on:keydown={handleKeydown}
    />
</div>

<div class="words" bind:this={wordsEl}>
    {#each words as word}
        <span class="word">
            {#each word as letter}
                <span class="letter">{letter}</span>
            {/each}
        </span>
    {/each}
</div>

<style lang="scss">
    .words {
        --line-height: 1em;
        --lines: 3;

        width: 100%;
        max-height: calc(var(--line-height) * var(--lines) * 1.42);
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        gap: 0.6em;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        line-height: var(--line-height);
        overflow: hidden;
        user-select: none;

        .letter {
            opacity: 0.4;
            transition: all 0.3s ease;

            &:global([data-letter='correct']) {
                opacity: 0.8;
            }

            &:global([data-letter='incorrect']) {
                color: var(--primary);
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
    }
</style>
```

I have attempted to use :global for the data attributes but this results in the following error message: ':global(...) not at the start of a selector sequence should not contain type or universal selectorssvelte(css-invalid-global-selector-position)'. Svelte and all other packages are up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message:

```
:global(...) not at the start of a selector sequence should not contain type or universal selectors
```

means that compiled style is invalid CSS. See [Github issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/6272) and [Svelte playground](https://svelte.dev/repl/dbadcb85a5ae42e3b963784432ab0c0f?version=3.56.0)

To effectively target the `<span/>`s with the *data-letter* attribute, the selector should be placed inside the `:global` selector e.g

```css
.word > :global(.letter[data-letter="correct"]) {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.word > :global(.letter[data-letter="incorrect"]) {
  color: var(--primary);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Place the `.word > :global(...)` selectors outside of the `.words` selector.

Answer (score 1):

If the element is created via the markup of the component, as in this case, you do not need `:global` at all.

In general its usage should rarely be necessary as most if not all elements should be created by Svelte and thus have the necessary scoping classes.

Also, you can add attributes and classes via the markup as well, no need to mess with them in code.

Example:

```html
<script>
    let correct = 'world';
    let words = ['loner'];
</script>

<div class="words">
    {#each words as word}
        <span class="word">
            {#each word as letter, i}
                <span class="letter"
                    class:exists={correct.indexOf(letter) != -1}
                    class:correct={correct[i] == letter}>
                    {letter}
                </span>
            {/each}
        </span>
    {/each}
</div>

<style>
    .letter.exists { color: orange; }
    .letter.correct { color: green; }
</style>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/519f7f3434124deba82d79528b43bae0?version=4.1.0)

With a `data-attribute`:

```html
<span class="letter"
    data-letter={
        correct[i] == letter ? 'correct' :
        correct.indexOf(letter) != -1 ? 'exists' :
        undefined
    }>
...
<style>
    .letter[data-letter=exists] { color: orange; }
    .letter[data-letter=correct] { color: green; }
</style>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d4408b57afcc4657bb186fba91dd53d1?version=4.1.0)